# Unhide files that start with a dot on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, file-management, nautilus

I was looking into a folder where I normally store data that I've unpacked and found that some files I thought were lost were actually in a folder that started with a `.`. Using Nautilus the folder was invisible. Performing an `ls` command from terminal also didn't expose it. It was after I ran some Java app that I'm working on did it show itself. I was able to `cd` into the directory, and finally just renamed it so it was visible. What I would like to have though is so that it is no longer hidden in Nautilus, is this possible?

Comment: I don't use nautilus, but `ls -a` might help you in your shell. There should be some option in the preferences of nautilus to show hidden files.

Comment: Thanks for the help Walter Maier-Murdnelch that does make it easier to find in the shell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Nautilus, to display/hide files that start with `.` or end with `~`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.

Comment: Perfect that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Like Dennis said, in Nautilus, to display/hide files that start with `.` or end with `~`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.

Also `ls -a` will display all files in terminal, hidden or no.